# Проект C# генерирует файлы XML документации со случайными названиями. Как отключить?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

Всем привет!

Ситуация вот такая:

У меня в проекте установлена настройка генерации XML документации к проекту.
Однако, проект уже кучу раз менялся руками непосредственно в текстовом редакторе, поэтому руками мог допустить где-то ошибку.

**Суть проблемы:**

При первой компилляции проекта под Release создаётся файл документации с названием проекта.
При второй компилляции файл не перезаписывается, а создаётся новый с случайным названием.
В итоге всё начинает выглядеть пугающе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как победить этот недуг, в какие теги смотреть?

Comment: Может быть, у вас неправильные права на каталог с программой?

Comment: @VladD Проект лежит в папке которая является локальной копией проекта в TFS, соответственно права у папки "Только для чтения(Применимо только к файлам внутри)", но файл документации таким атрибутом не обладает.

Comment: А если переместить проект в папку, доступную для записи? Возможно, компилятор не может _удалить_ временный файл.

Comment: @VladD Это не единственный проект который лежит в TFS и генерирует документацию, но единственный в котором возникла такого рода проблема. Не думаю что проблема в папках, но сейчас попробую переместить в другую папку ради эксперимента.